# Elasticsearch service not working in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, services

I installed `elasticsearch` from the standard repo (version 1.7.3). I configured it as a development node (master true, data true, 1 shard, 0 replicas, host - localhost). I uncommented `START_DAEMON=true` in `/etc/default/elasticsearch` and then I ran `sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service`. And the service starts fine and `curl http://localhost:9200` gives me what I expect.

But if I try to create an index or import some data into it, it just hangs up and runs out of RAM (though it does not use the 20GB swap I have) actually doing nothing. If I try any search it gives back this kind of error:

```
{"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed]","status":503}
```

If I stop the service and start elastic manualy (i.e. `sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch`) it runs just fine withought any problems at all.

But I want it to run as a service withought having to keep a console window open and run it every time manualy. Is there something I missed?

Comment: At least on my config, i have it running as a service and `START_DAEMON` doesnt event exists on `/etc/default/elasticsearch` file.